# Getting Issue with jquery while displaying text into text field

Tags: jquery, html

I am making an application using jQuery.  In my app, the user enters some input like:
 **"We are going to party"**
and when he clicks on the convert button, the result should be:
**"V R GNG 2 PRTY"**.

But in my code, I am getting only last value as a result.

The code is at [pastebin.com/NWMavENb](http://pastebin.com/NWMavENb).
I want the result to be "V R GNG 2 PRTY".Here is my page you can download http://www.mediafire.com/?cj5lz68di25dzx2[2](http://www.mediafire.com/?cj5lz68di25dzx2) this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply changing the value every time, so only the last value is stored.  You need to keep track of the value and append to it.

Here is one way

```
if(words[i]=="Are"||words[i]=="are"||words[i]=="ARE")
{
    $("#cnvalue").val($("#cnvalue").val() + " R");
}
```

Comment: You forgot 'aRe' and 'arE' ;) Please you toLowerCase or toUpperCase for this.

Comment: Good suggestion... but you should suggest it to @Sandeep.

Comment: Dear sir, http://www.mediafire.com/?cj5lz68di25dzx2 please check my post and suggest me what i am doing wrong with my code

Answer (score 1):

For each of your conditional `if` tests (and yes there are many ways to do this), try

```
if(words[i].toLowerCase() == "going") // case-insensitive test
{
    words[i] = "GNG";
}
```

and then after the end of your loop, reassign the value to your destination element.

```
$("#cnvalue").val(words.join(' '));
```